# Proving $\lim a^{1/n} = 1$ without logarithms?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, logarithms, radicals

I was given this problem:

> Show if $a>1$ and $n>1$ ($n$ and $a$ are integers) then,
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{\frac{1}{n}}=1.$$

The obvious solution is the following:

Take the logarithm in base $a$ of $a^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and logarithm in base $a$ of 1 and you have,

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$.

Which is clearly true. Therefore it is equal to $1$.

But the questions ask if you can prove this without logarithms, any solutions?

Comment: Hmm... To what does $\lim \frac{1}{n}$ equal?

Comment: @Tolaso you would first have to prove that $x\mapsto a^x$ is continuous.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy That is an easy task. It can found almost everywhere ...

Comment: @Tolaso cool you might give a link to that.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy If you open any book of Real Analsis or Calculus, you'll find it in there. !!

Comment: @Tolaso ah... but that is via the definition $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$ and the OP wanted a proof without logarithms...and as Michael Galuza has said below, what about continuity at zero?

Answer (score 8):

The basic idea of an "elementary" proof, which I have from Kenneth A. Ross, *Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus*, is that it behooves us to consider the quantity $s_n := a^{1/n} - 1$, and show that this tends to zero.  [**Recommendation:** See if this hint is enough!]

I will leave you to prove the lemma that $s_n > 0$ for all $n \geq 1$, i.e., if $a > 1$, then $a^{1/n} > 1$ [Proof by contrapositive is the easiest.]

Proof (essentially, Ross): If $s_n = a^{1/n} - 1$, then $a^{1/n} = 1 + s_n$.  Raise both sides to the $n$th power and use the binomial formula, and the positivity of $s_n$:  For $n \geq 3$,

\begin{align}
a &= (a^{1/n})^n && = (1 + s_n)^{n}\\
&&& = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} s_n^k\\
&&& \geq 1 + n s_n.
\end{align}

Thus, $\displaystyle s_n \leq \frac{a-1}{n}$.  Use the Squeeze Theorem.

[I seem to remember that an argument in this direction works even for $0 < a < 1$, but since $s_n$ is negative in this case (though still $> -1$) you have to use the $k = 2$ term of the binomial series and watch your error bounds a little more.]

Answer (score 6):

Bernoulli's Inequality says that for $x\ge-n$,
$$
1+x\le\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\tag{1}
$$
For $x\ge-1$, $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$
(1+x)^{1/n}\le1+\frac xn\tag{2}
$$
Taking reciprocals, we get
$$
\left(1-\frac x{1+x}\right)^{1/n}\ge\frac1{1+\frac xn}\tag{3}
$$
Substituting $x\mapsto-\frac x{1+x}$ in $(3)$ yields
$$
(1+x)^{1/n}\ge\frac1{1-\frac x{1+x}\frac1n}\tag{4}
$$
Putting $(2)$ and $(4)$ together gives
$$
\frac1{1-\frac x{1+x}\frac1n}\le(1+x)^{1/n}\le1+\frac xn\tag{5}
$$
Taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ and using the Squeeze Theorem, shows that, for $x\gt-1$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x)^{1/n}=1\tag{6}
$$