# Find limit of ${a}^{\frac{1}{n}}$ if $ 0 < a \leq 1$ and $n\ \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

The first thing I was trying to do is to substitute $a$ with something like $1 \over b$ or $1 + \frac{1}{b}$, but I got no results. Then I tried to use Squeeze theorem here, but I also got confused because, for example, $(a + 1)^{1/n}$ is not a decreasing function.

Comment: What does $(a+1)^{1/n}$ have to do with it?

Comment: Do you know the mean value theorem?

Comment: Yes, I know about it, but it holds for $(a,b)$, not for $(a, b]$, doesn't it?

Comment: @Purifyingflames,look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867269/use-delta-epsilon-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-a-frac1n-1/1867299#1867299

Comment: You need to specify the the limit. Does $n \to 1$? Does $n \to 0$? Does $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without Loss of Generality, we assume $0<a<1$.  Let $x_n=(1/a)^{1/n}-1$ so that $0\le x_n$.  Then, we see using Bernoulli's Inequality that

$$a=\frac{1}{(1+x_n)^n}\le \frac{1}{1+nx_n}$$

whereupon isolating $x_n$ reveals

$$0 \le x_n \le \frac{1-a}{a\,n}\tag 1$$

Applying the squeeze theorem to $(1)$ yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}a^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{1+x_n}=1$$

Note for $a>1$, simply analyze the limit of $(1/a)^{1/n}$ using the same way forward.

Answer (score 2):

Let $b_n = a^{1/n}$.

Assume $a\neq 1$ ($a=1$ is easy.)

Use that $$\frac{1-b_n}{1-a} =\frac{1-b_n}{1-b_n^n}= \frac{1}{1+b_n+b_n^2+\cdots + b_n^{n-1}}$$ 
Use this to get a good lower and upper bound on $1-b_n$ for use with the squeeze theorem.

--

The Mean Value Theorem version is that $\frac{b_n^n-1}{b_n-1} = nc^{n-1}$ for some $c$ in $[b_n,1]$, and again using this to get upper and lower bounds on $1-b_n$.