# How to show that the sequence $a^{1/n}$ converges to $1$ when $n \to \infty$? (using the epsilon-delta definition)

Tags: real-analysis

**Goal:** To show that the sequence $a^{1/n}$ ($a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a>0$ ) converges to $1$ when $n \to \infty$?

**Attempt:** Given any $\epsilon >0$, we have to come up with an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have $|a^{1/n}-1|<\epsilon.$ I tried different cases $0<a<1$ and $a>1,$ but it seems to be a fruitless exercise. Any hints/suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint (assuming $a>1$). For large enough $n$ we have $1+n\epsilon >a$. But also, by binomial theorem (or Bernoulli)
$$(1+\epsilon)^n\ge1+n\epsilon.$$ If $0<a<1$ do the same with $1/a$ in place of $a$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I used that and it works. We choose $\epsilon\leq \sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}.$

Comment: For all $n\geq \alpha.$

Comment: Then we get $1\leq \alpha^{1/n}\leq 1+\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}.$

Comment: But how to get back to the definition from here.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1867269/321264.

Answer (score 3):

We may assume that $a\geq 1$ (if $0<a<1$ replace $a$ with $1/a$). Let $x=a-1\geq 0$ and use the [Bernoulli inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality),
$$1\leq a=(1+x)^{1/n}\leq 1+\frac{x}{n}=1+\frac{a-1}{n}.$$
Hence
$$|a^{1/n}-1|\leq \frac{a-1}{n}<\epsilon$$
as soon as $n>\frac{a-1}{\epsilon}$.

Comment: But what about $0<a<1$?

Comment: If $0<a<1$ replace $a$ with $1/a$. Then $(1/a)^{1/n}\to 1$ implies that $a^{1/n}\to 1$.

Comment: And how do you get back to the definition from this step? I am asking this because I already did what you have suggested, but I am not sure how to go back to the definition

Comment: @ShreyAryan See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at $a>1$. Then $|a^{1/n}-1|=a^{1/n}-1$ and we have
$$
a^{1/n}-1<\varepsilon\\
a^{1/n}<1+\varepsilon\\
a<(1+\varepsilon)^n
$$
Since $(1+\varepsilon)^n$ is increasing and unbounded with respect to $n$, it will eventually become larger than $a$, and we have our $N$. Specifically, setting $N\geq \log_{1+\varepsilon}(a)=\frac{\ln a}{\ln(1+\varepsilon)}$ will work.