# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a}$ where 0 < a

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a}$ 

Disclaimer: Since this is a sequence the fact that n approaches infinity is obvious, therefore I omitted it in the limit notation. 
My idea is to analyze two cases: 1) $ 1 < a$ and 2) $ 0 < a < 1$. 
(1) $1 < a$-n
$$\sqrt[n]{a} = 1 + t_n$$  And $t_n >0 $Now, I use the binomial formula to get $$a >1+nt_n \Rightarrow t_n<\frac{a-1}{n} \iff 0 <\lim t_n<\lim \frac{a-1}{n} \Rightarrow \lim t_n =0$$
And since $\lim t_n = 0 $ $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a}= 1$ 
Then, I will use the same method to prove the second case. 
Is it a correct way to do this? If so, is there an easier way?

Comment: This is a good method. For the second case, you can apply the first to $a^{-1}$.

Comment: One small addition - do not write $\lim t_n$ until you have shown the limit exists. Once you have $0<t_n<\frac{a-1}n$, you can conclude.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2478971/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1867269/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $0 < a < 1$,
there is a interesting trick.
Bernoulli's inequality
does not seem
directly applicable.

However,
if you write
$a=\dfrac1{1+b}$
where
$b
= \dfrac1{a}-1
\gt 0$,
then
$\dfrac1{a^n}
=(1+b)^n
\ge 1+nb
\gt nb
$,
then
$a^n
\lt \dfrac1{nb}
\to 0
$.

Answer (score -1):

Let $$\:a^n=e^{\ln \left(a^n\right)}=e^{n\cdot \ln \left(a\right)}$$
Then 
$$\sqrt[n]{a} =a^{\frac{1}{n}}=e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln \left(a\right)}$$
Also 
$$u = \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{n}\ln \left(a\right)\right) = 0 \implies \lim _{u\to \:0}\left(e^u\right)=1$$
Therefore
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a} = 1$$

Comment: This is simply an elaboration of the other (not great) answer, but with additional issues.