# Prove $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }\sqrt[n]{a}=1$, if $a>0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I tried solving by using $\log$ and got $\log(a)/n = \log (1)$ which after applying limit (of $n \to \infty$) gives $0= \log(1)$. Is this right?

Comment: Certainly $\log1$ is $0$.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2506582/42969

Comment: @RuRu Ly Hii!! Welcome to MSE . Kindly write statement of question in question also ( apart from title) . Also  you should add context of problem , that is  source(if textbook)  . Also see on site tour , How to ask a good question .

Answer (score 0):

Write , $a^{\frac{1}{n}} = e^{\ln(a^{\frac{1}{n}} )}= e^{\frac{1}{n} \cdot \ln(a) } $

Now , just apply the limit.